# PECL installed & loaded but http_negotiate_language not found

Tags: php, apache, pecl

I face an awkward problem:

```
Call to undefined function http_negotiate_language()
```

- on a fresh installed server (ubuntu raring)
- PECL correctly installed, php.ini updated
- PECL modules are loaded without errors

and:

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('http')); // return true, everything is fine
```

I must miss something but what ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got version 2 of pecl_http, which dropped the function-style API. The supported call is now `http\Env::negotiateLanguage` (see the [negotiateLanguage docs](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/Env/negotiateLanguage)).

You can either update your code or try to run

```bash
# pecl uninstall pecl_http
# pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6
```

to downgrade.